# Python 3.5 PyMC - suppress the progress showing

Tags: python, python-3.5, pymc

on pymc version '2.3.6' in Python 3.5

I am trying to suppress the progress update given when running the MCMC:

```
observation = pymc.Poisson('obs', lambda_, value= count_data, observed= True)
model = pymc.Model([observation, lambda_1, lambda_2, kappa])
mcmc = pymc.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(20000, 1000, 1)
```

Any idea how i could do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the value for `verbose` that does that is `-1`. I would use the following more explicit syntax:

```
mcmc.sample(iter=20000, lenght=1000, verbose=-1)
```

Alternatively:

```
mcmc.sample(iter=20000, lenght=1000, progress_bar=0)
```

Cheers,

A.

PS: you can look yourself in the source code of `installation_directory/pymc/MCMC.py`.
The installation directory can be found using:

```
pymc.__file__
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs here](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelfitting.html#the-sampler-class), the sampler is called like that:

```
sample(iter, length, verbose, ...)
```

This would mean, that your are explicitly activating verbose with your 3rd argument:

```
mcmc.sample(20000, 1000, 1)  # Make the third argument a zero
```

Sadly i can't test it at the moment, but this should be a good first step (if i read the docs correctly).

Comment: Thanks for looking but the 
mcmc.sample(50000, 10000, verbose= 0)
did not work:  I can still see the progress showing.